# Issue with Ruby gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install json on windows as follows, but its not working. Please help me with possible resoultion for the same.

```
C:\Ruby193\bin>gem install --local json-1.8.1.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json-1.8.1.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20140725-4216-11o740j.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Windows always gives trouble. Ruby on rails is not built for windows environment. Try using in ubuntu, you will get more support.

Comment: @ashwinkumar Rails actually works okay on Windows. Some things (e.g. compiling gems) are just a bit different and most people do use it on Linux or OS X. Still, Windows is a supported platform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RubyGems 2.4.1 will not build native extensions in Ruby version 1.9.3 and earlier on Windows.

You will need to downgrade RubyGems to 1.8.29.
To do this run the following command:

```
gem update --system 1.8.29
```

Check gem version:

```
gem -v
1.8.29
```

Now try your command again:

```
gem install --local json-1.8.1.gem
```

ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/k19SeJijpKU/discussion

Comment: As the issue is with RubyGems > 2.4.0, you don't need to go all the way down to 1.8.29.  Going to 2.3.0 worked for me:  'gem update --system 2.3.0'