# How to resolve "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hello please help me to resolve this error.I wanted to design a chat application using private_pub gem.i add the code gem private_pub in my gem file.when i run the command bundle in command prompt it gave the following error.
Errors:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20141218-3932-nyliv2.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/http_pars
er.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/ht
tp_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing http_parser.rb (0.6.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install http_parser.rb -v '0.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I already have all installation before my system.I am using ruby-1.9.3, rails-4 and i already installed the proper devkit for ruby 1.9.3.Please provide me the step by step process to solve the above error.

Here is my gemfile.

```
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
gem 'private_pub'
```

Answer (score 0):

as Show in Error Report You Need To insatll "gem http_parser.rb (0.6.0)" before installing gem private_pub.
to install http_parser.rb (0.6.0),
add gem 'http_parser.rb', '~> 0.6.0' in your gem file.then run the command bundle.

Comment: Hello dear,As per you after adding gem 'http_parser.rb', '~> 0.6.0'
in gem file and run bundle command,the same error is showing.

Comment: refer this ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950844/issue-with-ruby-gem-install?