# after entering 'bundle install' on command line I get "make sure that 'gem install json -v 1.8.2' succeeds before bundling"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems, devkit

I've been following this lynda tutorial online on 'Ruby on Rails.' I've downloaded Ruby, devkit and rails on to my computer. After I created sample_app and tried to run **bundle install**, but it keeps telling me **make sure that 'gem install json -v 1.8.2' succeeds before bundling"** I try to run **gem install json -v 1.8.2** and other variations including "gem install json -v 1.8.2 --verbose", "gem install json --platform=ruby" but everytime I get an error saying that it **failed to build gem native extensions.** The same thing happened when I was following the downloading devkit tutorial and I tried to install JSON as per its instructions. I've tried using **gem update system 2.3.0** but that doesn't work either. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this will happen on Windows because not all the commands are availible. I would recommended that you either use VirtualBox with an Ubuntu image or use [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem myself.  I am working my way from Windows to a Mac but not quite there just yet.  Windows is ok for Rails development (been doing so for 3 years) although it does present some unique issues occasionally.  Check out the following link to downgrade RubyGems to 1.8.29 and then try running bundle install again.

[Issue with Ruby gem install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950844/issue-with-ruby-gem-install)